# Откуда берется "мусор" в векторе?

Tags: вектор, delphi-6

Доброго времени суток.

Мне нужно преобразовать двумерный массив в одномерный. Сделал это в простом, элементарном цикле и... обнаружил, что в массив, кроме элементов матрицы, попадают какие-то "левые, мусорные" значения.
Вывожу элементы матрицы в `ListBox`. Сначала идут "мусорные" элементы, а те, которые нужны мне - в конце. Что может работать не так?

Код кнопки, в которой описан алгоритм:

```
procedure TForm2.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  counter := 1;
  ListBox1.Clear;
  for i := 1 to n do
    for j := 1 to n do
    begin
      vec[counter] := a[i, j];
      ListBox1.Items.Add(inttostr(vec[counter]));
      counter := counter + 1;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Как объявлены массивы?

Comment: @MBo, 
a: array [1..n, 1..n]of integer;
vec: array [1..n] of integer;

Comment: Размер vec слишком мал

Comment: @MBo, Точно! У меня же 2 массива в 1! Подскажете, как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно задать достаточный размер для `vec` - n<sup>2</sup> элементов:

```
vec: array [1..n*n] of integer
```